# Printing an array of float numbers in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

I am a anew user to MIPS and I am having problems in printing an array of floating point numbers that I am taking in from the user and also I am having problems with finding the most repeated floating point number.

Here is the code in which I am able to take in user input but not able to print the array.

```
    #data declarations: declare variable names used in program, storage allocated in RAM

                         .data
 max:            .word 12
 temp:           .word 1
 num:            .space 96
 input1:         .asciiz "Enter a number:\n" #prints the statement 
 output1:        .asciiz "The number that is repeated more often than any other is "
 output2:        .asciiz " with "
 output3:        .asciiz " repititions.\n"
 output4:        .asciiz "The array contains the following: \n"

                    .text 

                    .globl    main    

 main:
 lw     $t1, temp
 lw     $t2, max


 Loop:
 la     $a0, input1   # $a0 = address of input1
 li     $v0, 4          # $v0 = 4  --- this is to call print_string()
 syscall
 li     $v0, 6
 syscall
 la     $t0, num
 s.s    $f0, 0($t0)
 addi   $t0, $t0, 8
 addi   $t1, $t1, 1
 ble    $t1, $t2, Loop

 la         $a0, output4
 li     $v0, 4
 syscall
 l.s    $f12, 0($t0)
 li     $v0, 2
 syscall
 jr     $ra
```

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of "having problems"? When you single-step through your code in an emulator like MARS, which line doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: My code is taking in input from the user perfectly but I am facing problems when I am trying to print the array that contains the floating numbers.

Comment: Here are some things that have me scratching my head. `temp` and `max` are uninitialized memory, so when you load the contents of that memory into `$t1` and `$t2`, results could be random. What are you trying to do? Also, this doesn't look like a function you're calling from somewhere else, so why does it end with `jr $ra` instead of a syscall 10 (end program)?

Comment: _"I am facing problems"_ doesn't really say anything. _What_ problems are you having _exactly_?

Comment: Our professor have not taught us to use syscall 10 to end the program but we just end the program with jr $ra. I am using the temp and max variable because we are asking user for only 12 float numbers and so that works on the floating point numbers and also use those variable for inputting the floating point numbers in the array.

Comment: I do not really know how to print an array of floating point numbers?

Comment: Read a float from the current position in the array into `$f12`. Execute syscall 2 to print it. Repeat.

Comment: can you guys show me how to print an array of integers using the registers I have already defined in my program than it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
    max:            .word 3
    temp:           .word 1
    num:            .space 96
    input1:         .asciiz "Enter a number:\n" #prints the statement 
    output1:        .asciiz "The number that is repeated more often than any other is "
    output2:        .asciiz " with "
    output3:        .asciiz " repititions.\n"
    output4:        .asciiz "The array contains the following: \n"

.text

.globl    main    
 main:
    lw     $t1, temp # loop counter
    lw     $t2, max  # upper bound
    la     $t0, num  # address of array

 Loop:
    # print input prompt
    la     $a0, input1
    li     $v0, 4     
    syscall

    # get value from the user
    li     $v0, 6
    syscall

    # move user provided value from $f0 to array
    s.s    $f0, 0($t0)

    # move to the next position in the array, increment loop counter
    addi   $t0, $t0, 4
    addi   $t1, $t1, 1
    ble    $t1, $t2, Loop

    # restore loop counter, and array address for printing
    lw $t1, temp
    la $t0, num

    # print output prompt
    la $a0, output4
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
print_loop:
    # print number from the array
    l.s    $f12, 0($t0)
    li     $v0, 2
    syscall

    # print space
    la $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    # increment loop counter and move to next value
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    ble $t1, $t2, print_loop
```

Here is how it works:

```
Enter a number:
2.3
Enter a number:
3.14
Enter a number:
5.55
The array contains the following: 
2.3 3.14 5.55
```